# Create a popover in iPad like google suggestions

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to create a suggestions list in my app just like the google suggestions in safari in ipad . Can anyone know how to implement please help me .

Comment: Hi. you use the below URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a popover suggestion page in iOS using following Link.

[SuggestionsList](https://github.com/tetek/SuggestionsList)

I hope Its help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIPopOverController.

Add, *UIPopoverControllerDelegate* as delegate to the ViewController.

Declare like this in .h file.

UIPopoverController *popover;

in .m file..

```
Inventory_VC *vc = [[Inventory_VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"Inventory_VC" bundle:nil];

vc.Search_Text = self.Search_Text;

[vc setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(360, 600)];

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
popover.delegate = self;

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:theSearchBar.bounds inView:theSearchBar
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Based on your requirement u can add any thing be it a UIView/UIPickerView/UIDatePicker etc. onto the Popover.